# Dilemma in calling constructor of generic class

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization, generics

I have this generic singleton that looks like this:

```
public class Cache<T>
{
    private Dictionary<Guid, T> cachedBlocks;

    // Constructors and stuff, to mention this is a singleton

    public T GetCache(Guid id)
    {
        if (!cachedBlocks.ContainsKey(id))
            cachedBlocks.Add(id, LoadFromSharePoint(id))
        return cachedBlocks[id];
    }

    public T LoadFromSharePoint(Guid id)
    {
        return new T(id)    // Here is the problem.
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> Cannot create an instance of type T because it does not have the new() constraint.

I have to mention that I *must* pass that `id` parameter, and there is no other way to do so. Any ideas on how to solve this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: a related q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550173/instantiating-a-generic-type?rq=1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Normally you would constrain the type `T` to a type that has a default constructor and call that. Then you'd have to add a method or property to be able to provide the value of `id` to the instance.

```
public static T LoadFromSharePoint<T>(Guid id)
    where T : new()     // <-- Constrain to types with a default constructor
{
    T value = new T();
    value.ID = id;
    return value;
}
```

---

**Alternatively** since you specify that you *have* to provide the `id` parameter through the constructor, you can invoke a parameterized constructor using reflection. *You must be sure the type defines the constructor you want to invoke*. You cannot constrain the generic type `T` to types that have a particular constructor other than the default constructor. (E.g. `where T : new(Guid)` does not work.)

For example, I *know* there is a constructor `new List<string>(int capacity)` on `List<T>`, which can be invoked like this:

```
var type = typeof(List<String>);
object list = Activator.CreateInstance(type, /* capacity */ 20);
```

Of course, you might want to do some casting (to `T`) afterwards.

Comment: it sounds like a great idea, but I can not say value.ID = id, it just wont let me, tho I'm pretty close to getting it. Any other tips? Thanks a lot so far by the way :)

Comment: @AlexOltean The second part of my answer is an _alternative_, for when you cannot say `value.ID = id`. Try that :D

Comment: @AlexOltean while this answer might work, its really not the right way to do at all. Reflection is totally unwarranted here. Besides being slower, its not the right approach. Your code is more expressive of what it does without reflection. With reflection you're making things obscure. You will learn that with time.

Comment: @nawfal I am not in favor of reflection. My first suggestion is essentially the same as yours, but you showed it on the class and with an interface. I interpreted the _"I must pass that id parameter, and there is no other way to do so"_ literally, and then the only solution is reflection, as you'll have to agree.

Answer (score 7):

To do this you should specify what `T` is. Your `Cache<T>` can hold anything? `Tiger`, `Fridge` and `int` as well? That is not a sound design. You should **constrain** it. You need an instance of `T` which will take a `Guid` to construct the instance. That's not a generic `T`. Its a very specific `T`. Change your code to:

```
public class Cache<T> where T : Cacheable, new()
{
    private Dictionary<Guid, T> cachedBlocks;

    // Constructors and stuff, to mention this is a singleton

    public T GetCache(Guid id)
    {
        if (!cachedBlocks.ContainsKey(id))
            cachedBlocks.Add(id, LoadFromSharePoint(id))
        return cachedBlocks[id];

       //you're first checking for presence, and then adding to it
       //which does the same checking again, and then returns the
       //value of key again which will have to see for it again. 
       //Instead if its ok you can directly return

       //return cachedBlocks[id] = LoadFromSharePoint(id);

       //if your LoadFromSharePoint is not that expensive.
       //mind you this is little different from your original 
       //approach as to what it does.
    }

    public T LoadFromSharePoint(Guid id)
    {
        return new T { Key = id };    // Here is no more problem.
    }
}

public interface Cacheable
{
    Guid Key { get; set; }
}
```

Now derive all the cacheables (whatever `T`s that you will pass it for `Cache<T>`) from the interface `Cacheable`.

Comment: That would work too, especially because I would avoid using reflection

Comment: @AlexOltean glad it worked. I commented on the other post without seeing your this comment. Cheers

Comment: @AlexOltean i edited my answer, you can make your code faster with my suggestion. Only that now it updates the value corresponding to id each time (if id key is present) and returns it in one go. It depends on how expensive your `LoadFromSharePoint` which i think is not at all.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the constructor of a Generic Type without any constraint, and within the class, the syntax *where T : class, new()* needs to be used

This enables to change values of attributes (fields) - not only get/set properties) at runtime depending the target class used

First, declaring the generic class:

```
public class Foo<T>   where T : class, new()
{
    public T oneEmptyElement()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public T setAttribute(string attributeName, string attributeValue)
    {
        T objT = new T();
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo fld = typeof(T).GetField(attributeName);
        if (fld != null)
        {
            fld.SetValue(objT, attributeValue);
        }
        return objT;
    }

    public List<T> listOfTwoEmptyElements()
    {
        List<T> aList = new List<T>();
        aList.Add(new T());
        aList.Add(new T());
        return aList;
    }
}
```

Declare then a potential target class:

```
public class Book
{
    public int name;
}
```

And finally the call can be done like this:

```
        Foo<Book> fooObj = new Foo<Book>();

        Book aBook = fooObj.oneEmptyElement();
        aBook.name = "Emma";

        Book anotherBook = fooObj.setAttribute("name", "John");

        List<Book> aListOfBooks = fooObj.listOfTwoEmptyElements();
        aListOfBooks[0].name = "Mike";
        aListOfBooks[1].name = "Angelina";

        Console.WriteLine(aBook.name);    //Output Emma
        Console.WriteLine(anotherBook.name);    //Output John
        Console.WriteLine(aListOfBooks[0].name); // Output Mike
        Console.WriteLine(aListOfBooks[1].name);  // Output Angelina
```