# C#: How to get the correct method in a generic class with reflection in case of ambiguous match?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I have the following method:

```
object Create(Type type)
{
    var constructor = type.GetConstructor(typeof(int));
    return constructor?.Invoke(new object[] {42});
}
```

This method works for the most of the types, either finding a constructor and invoking it, ot returning null. But, when passed the following type, it throws `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException`:

```
class C<T>
{
    public C(int v) { Console.WriteLine("int"); }
    public C(T v) { Console.WriteLine("T"); }
}

Create(typeof(C<int>));
```

This is expected, as there are two constructors with the same signature, but the question is: how to invoke a specific constructor (in this case, the one which will print `"int"`)? If I use `GetConstructors()` and enumerate them, I get two exactly same constructors. It seems that `ConstructorInfo` and `ParameterInfo` APIs do not provide any info to distinguish them: both are non-generic methods and parameter types of both are `Int32`.

The same question also applies to methods other than constructors which follow the same pattern.

Comment: Why are you using reflection in a generic scenario? Generic exists so you do not have to resort to messy stuff - like dynamic, object or reflection - that ruins compile time type safety.

Comment: @Christopher my Create method has nothing to do with generics and always wants to invoke a constructor with specific signature (that is the type contract). I just want it to continue working as intended in case someone passes a type like I described.

Comment: Generics can be used to create instance, with a simple constraint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15003163/3346583 | However, if you got a Create functions that sounds suspiciously like the Factory pattern.

Comment: Well, technically reflection is right. Reflection-wise there is an ambiguity. You will have to be specific about which one you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential way to disambiguate the constructors is to look at the [MetadataToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.metadatatoken?view=netcore-3.1) property of the ConstructorInfo:

```
// Get the ConstructorInfo for C<T>.C(int):
var c1 = typeof(C<>).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int) });

// Get the matching ConstructorInfo for C<int>.C(int):
var c2 = typeof(C<int>).GetConstructors().Single(c => c.MetadataToken == c1.MetadataToken);

c2.Invoke(new object[] { 42 }); // Outputs "int"
```

I say "potential" because, although I got the desired output on my machine when I tested the code with .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.7, I'm not sufficiently familiar with .NET internals to understand whether this approach is guaranteed to work.

Comment: This seems good enough as a short-term solution. In a long term I decided to change the contract to require a static factory method instead (without any attempts to resolve ambiguities), so the consumers of the API can have as many constructors as they like without violating the contract (since it is possible to have identical constructors come from multiple generic parameters neither of which is preferable).